# Error in Importing Boolean variable

Tags: java, netbeans

I have two classes , one called AdminMenu class where variable VoteCycle is a boolean variable that enables a voter to vote provided that the VoteCycle is enabled and another class called LogInMenu where I would like to utilize it.

I'm doing this for my school project.

The problem I have is that even if I select enable which is meant to change the boolean value to true , I'm still getting the false output.. If you don't understand what I mean, my code below should explain it.

Its very basic programming.

The Class

```
 public class AdminMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public boolean VoteCycle;
```

The method

```
private void VoteComboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
if(vCycle.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("True"))
{
VoteCycle=true;
}
else if(vCycle.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("False"))
{
VoteCycle=false;
}
}
```

This is the class where I would like to use the variable to allow users to log in.
The class is called LogInMenu().
At the start of the class I created an object of the class where the variable was defined in using

```
AdminMenu AdminMenu=new AdminMenu();
DataValidation validate=new DataValidation();
ConnectDB db=new ConnectDB();
```

I will just post the relevant code for this class:

```
private void EnterBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
if(AdminMenu.VoteCycle)
{
     String Voter=voter.getText();

     boolean detail = false;

    if (validate.Verify(Voter))// Validates Data
    {
        try
        {
            detail = db.VoterLogIn(Voter);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        if (detail)
        {
            new VoterMenu().setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Username or Password entered is incorrect");// error message
        }    
    } 
}
else
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Voting is currently disabled", "Error",     JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
}
```

Even after selecting the combo box option to enabled, I return to the LogInMenu class
and if i attempt to login I receive the "Voting is currently disabled" error.

I would really appreciate any help offered , Thank you!

P.S : I'm unsure how to use a toggle button and allow its state to be kept when logging into the administrators menu or just how to use the toggle button at all.

So instead i'm using a combox box to set my variables values.

Comment: Jesus your code is a mess! Please name your buttons and don't have variable names like "val", or "x". Nobody has any idea what they are. Also PLEASE learn to use standard naming conventions for Java.

Comment: And don´t paste THIS MUCH code. Nobody will actually read all this, exspecially since at least 9/10 of it is not needed. We for example don´t care a bit about your `initComponents()`. We know generally, what happens in there, no need to paste it...

Comment: There is no 'error in importing' here. There is an unexpected (to you) runtime behaviour. Please adjust your title.

Comment: Please use [standard java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). It's just too much effort to mentally have to decide your code into normal names.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I have is that even if I select enable which is meant to
>   change the boolean value to true , I'm still getting the false
>   output..

Because, the elements of your `JComboBox` `vCycle` are `{ "Disabled", "Enabled", " " }` whereas, you are checking the `selectedItem` for `true` and `false`. You should compare the selected value of `vCycle` for `Diabled` or `Enabled` instead of `true` and `false`.

```
if(vCycle.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Disabled"))
{
VoteCycle=true;
}
else if(vCycle.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Enabled"))
{
VoteCycle=false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from checking for the *wrong* text value of True and False instead of Enabled and Disabled, your code doesn't handle the case where it's *neither*.

Change your code to the *single* line:

```
VoteCycle = vCycle.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Enabled");
```

Not only is it less code, and more readable, it caters (one way or another) for the *neither* case.

Comment: That was very stupid of me. I changed the code as you said , but I'm receiving the false value output.. It looks like the value isn't changing when I use the variable in the LogInMenu class.

Comment: Are you using the same instance? Better post the code calling the method in question.

Comment: Everything is in the question. VoteComboBoxActionPerformed is in the AdminMenu class and EnterBtnActionPerformed is in the LogInMenu class , the class where im calling it. I created an object called AdminMenu so I could access the variable , its all used in the same instance.